# Conversion of date from '1 January 1970 00:00:00.000' to 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ' format in Mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement wherein I have to convert the date from format '1 January 1970 00:00:00.000' as '1970-01-01T00:00:00' in Mule4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 

--- 
{ 
   Result: "1 January 1970 00:00:00.000" as LocalDateTime {format: "d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"} as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
}
```

Comment: Why is the last cast to DateTime instead of LocalDateTime?

Comment: LocalDateTime  does not represent a point in time and uses a fixed local timezone. DateTime has a construct of timezone associated with it. i didn't put a timezone in the final output  and i think your question stems from that very fact?